# ipython-notebook: Syntax highlighting and autosave

Tags: syntax-highlighting, ipython, jupyter-notebook

I am working a lot with ipython-notebook. Is there any way to highlight open and closed brackets? I am asking because I saw in some videos with Wes McKiney that he used some kind of syntax highlighting for brackets. Moreover, is there any way to autosave in ipython-notebook?

Finally, do you have any other modifications or browser extensions which you can recommend for ipython-notebook?

Best Regards

Andy

Answer (score 1):

> I am working a lot with ipython-notebook. Is there any way to highlight open and closed brackets? [...] Moreover, is there any way to autosave in ipython-notebook?

All this should be on development version.

> Finally, do you have any other modifications or browser extensions which you can recommend for ipython-notebook?

You can also look for tricks and extension on [IPython Wiki](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/wiki). There are a bunch of those.

Comment: Hi Matt, thank you very much. I have already downloaded the development version and it supports autosave. However, I have still no highlighting for open/closed brackets although Strings and operators are colored. Do you have an idea, what I can do?

Comment: It has been disabled with a library update that changed the way to do it, I'll open an [issue](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/3335) to re-enable it.